# Uncompiled user controls running in compiled web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Is it possible to compile my web forms app and deploy it, then drop some user controls in it later to add functionality? (assuming I had taken into account being able to load user controls dynamically in the first place) Can someone point me in a direction to how this might be done?

Comment: To clarify -- you're deploying the assemblies only and no source code, correct?

Comment: Yes when I deploy it, assemblies and the relating .aspx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is somewhat related but uses razor views instead of ascx controls - http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is no, you can't drag and drop or add new code for new user controls to precompiled pages.

But you can create functionality that loads user controls dynamically, where you store what pages get controls in a database, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I never actually tried it but I would say it is possible. You will have to do some tricks with IIS, GAC and Virtual Directories, but it should work.

The principle of how it could be done can be found here -> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/ctrlreuse.aspx

Comment: I don't know if that is really dynamic. I could just add an existing project to the solution and add a reference to it. That article looks like it does the same thing, but the hard way.

Comment: You would have to compile the project with the user controls you are trying to add and configure it on IIS on some common web application. In the consumer application it could be done by dynamically loading the assembly from GAC based on some configuration. I think it should work out pretty well, but I'm not really sure whether this is a good idea in first place.